# Firefox browser opens but doesn't load any web pages

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am just starting out with Ubuntu 20.04 on a WSL machine and I'm trying to get webpages to show up in Firefox or Chrome, however the latter doesn't even load. Any web browser would work as long as it can download files when clicking on links.

I believe my machine is connected to the internet because I can wget files from FTP sites and online folders, but I need to download a tar.gz file listed on https://gdal.org/download.html. Can I do this without a web browser?

I have tried a few fixes mentioned, but nothing seems to work.

- I entered config in the URL but it didn't take me to the IPV6 page
- The "Sign-in to Firefox" dropdown option does not bring any page
- The "Add-ons" and "Preferences" dropdown for disabling Ubuntu addons doesn't show anything either
- I made sure that "Work Offline" is unchecked.

I'm new here, so please ask for more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the file you want to download from a site, then `wget` is your friend. For example, if you want to download the latest `tar.gz`, the URL would be `https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz`, which you can call with `wget`:

```
wget "https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz" .
```

If you're not sure what the link is and you want to see a complete list to choose from via the command line, do this:

1. Download the web page (and hope it's not one of those fully JavaScript-composited things):

```
wget "https://gdal.org/download.html" -O site.html
```

2. List all links contained in the file:

```
cat site.html | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*"
```

You will see something like this:

```
https://gdal.orgdownload.html
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/edit//master/gdal/doc/source/download.rst
http://schema.org/Article
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.1/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.0/gdal-3.2.0.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.0/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.0/gdal-3.2.0.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.4/gdal-3.1.4.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.1.4/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.4/gdal-3.1.4.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.3/gdal-3.1.3.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.1.3/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.3/gdal-3.1.3.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.2/gdal-3.1.2.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.1.2/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.2/gdal-3.1.2.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.1/gdal-3.1.1.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.1.1/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.1/gdal-3.1.1.tar.gz.md5
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.0/gdal-3.1.0.tar.gz
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.1.0/gdal/NEWS
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.1.0/gdal-3.1.0.tar.gz.md5
...
```

3. Copy the link for the file you wish to download
4. Use `wget`:

```
wget "https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz" .
```

Hope this gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Using terminal browser like [`links2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/links2) may be an option too.